# How best to parse/split a <div> based on <br /> tags

Tags: perl

I have a  tag containing a multiline address that I'd like to split into single lines so that I can identify the city, postcode, etc.

For example

```
<div>Ministry of Magic
    <br />Whitehall
    <br />London
    <br />SW1A 2AA
</div>
```

I can do it no problem with the split function, for example (assuming the address div is in the variable $text)

```
use feature 'say';
my @lines = split qr{<br\s?/>}, $text;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    say $line;
}
```

displays

```
Ministry of Magic
Whitehall
London
SW1A 2AA
```

However, I'm well aware that [using a regex to parse HTML is verboten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) so I thought I'd give it a try using `HTML::TreeBuilder / HTML::Element` but I'm not sure how to grab the content. I can do a look_down for the 'br' tags, but it only returns the `<br />` tags themselves. This is not surprising because a `<br>` element cannot contain content, but I don't know what syntax to use instead.

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new();
my @content = $tree->parse($text)->guts()->look_down(_tag => 'br');
foreach my $line (@content) {
    say $line->as_HTML;
}
```

displays

```
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

So, my questions are: 1) should I stick with the regex or use HTML::TreeBuilder, and 2) if I should use HTML::TreeBuilder, how I can I extract the four lines of text I'm interested in?

Comment: A `<br/>` is just a line break, there is nothing else "in" the tag. You want an expression for the text *between* (i.e. around) these tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your case is (and will always be) as simple as you describe, then I'd stick with the regexes. Before you cry havoc and release the dogs on me, *think* for a second:

Yes, it's true that regexes cannot parse HTML. But we are not parsing HTML here. We are parsing a very, *very* tiny subset of HTML within a `<div>`, which is easily handled by a simple regex. Using a full-blown parsing library would, to me, be rather like using a sledgehammer to crack a walnut.

I would personally upgrade your regex a bit to `m!<\s*br\s*/?\s*>!` to catch (slightly) mangled HTML, and, as with anything, *test* with every valid and invalid input you can put together.

Comment: Thanks @type_outcast, my case is as simple as I described. I agree with all you say and that's the thought process I went through. I was just curious to know if there was a better way and also to know how to deal with 'br' tags (but I could perhaps make a separate question out of that).